# JavaMail with proxy not connecting

Tags: java, proxy, connection, jakarta-mail, ports

i have a class that is called "NotifiationService":
@Service("notificacionService")
public class NotificacionServiceImpl implements NotificacionService{

```
//servicio llama a repositorio
@Autowired
@Qualifier("notificacionService")
private NotificacionService notificacionService;

    @Override
    public void send(String to, String subject, String text) {

        //proxy
        Properties p = System.getProperties();
        p.setProperty("proxySet","true");
        p.setProperty("socksProxyHost","MYPROXY");
        p.setProperty("socksProxyPort","MYPORT");

        Properties props = new Properties();

        // smtp.gmail.com
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");

        // TLS
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");

        // port
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port","465");

        //
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", "reciever@gmail.com");


        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");



        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        session.setDebug(true);

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        try {

            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("sender@gmail.com"));


            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));


            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(text);

            //
            Transport t = session.getTransport("smtp");
            t.connect("sender@gmail.com","senderpassword");
            t.sendMessage(message,message.getAllRecipients());
            t.close();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

As you can see i have tried to configure a proxy, since the computer is connected to one that redirects the traffic. So even adding all the specifications about the proxy, it keeps giving me an error saying:

```
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 465; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
```

I have also tried different ports like: 25,485,587 and none of the respond, so i think its a problem with the proxy.

To be able to find the information about the proxy that is implemented i have typed this command in the console:

```
reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" | find /i "proxyserver"
```

and it responds with:

```
ProxyServer    REG_SZ    MYPROXY:MYPORT
```

If i type: "ping google.com" in cmd, it says its inaccessible

Is there a way to be able to connect from java with javamail to gmail and be able to send an email with the current configuration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not working after setting the SOCKS properties, most likely your proxy server is just a web proxy server and not a SOCKS proxy server.  The [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#proxy) has pointers to other software that will allow to tunnel connections through a web proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

Since JavaMail 1.6.2, You can set proxy authentication properties for Session object for sending emails.

Refer to the following documentation link.
https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/

The following properties are introduced newly and works fine with Proxy Authentication (Basic).

> mail.smtp.proxy.host
>
> mail.smtp.proxy.port
>
> mail.smtp.proxy.user
>
> mail.smtp.proxy.password

Answer (score 0):

To clarify at least one point concerning the usage of https.proxySet=true and http.proxySet=true.

[JDK-4632974](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4632974) proxySet=false is ignored for HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream

"The use of property http.proxySet was eliminated in favor of simply testing
for the presence of the http.proxyHost property. This property existed up to
JDK1.0.2 but was removed for JDK1.1 in 1996."

In other words, do not use proxySet as it serves no purpose. It is non-existing Java system property nowadays.